# Android XStream Object Java WebService

Tags: android, android-layout, ksoap2, xstream

I have a running `webservice` and I want to call the Method of the Webservice and should show the result in a `TextView` on the mobile. The Webservice is working very well, for testing I can get a `string response` from webservice. But I want to get an `Xstream Object`.
I have created an `Xstream object` and it's working locally.

When I call the webservice method to get the xstream object using `KSOAP2` I get the exception `java.lang.classcastexception:org.ksopa2.soapFault`

Please help.

```
package com.pxr.tutorial.soap.weather;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope; 
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;  
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;   
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver;


public class Main extends Activity {


private String METHOD_NAME = "getName"; // our webservice method name
private String NAMESPACE = "http://webservice.app"; // Here package
                                                            // name in
                                                            // webservice
                                                            // with reverse
                                                            // order.
private String SOAP_ACTION = "http://webservice.app/getName"; // NAMESPACE
                                                                    // +
                                                                    // method
public TextView t; // name

private static String URL = "http://ip/WS/services/Service?wsdl";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Initialize soap request + add parameters
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("user", "user");
    request.addProperty("passwort", "passwort");

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    // Make the soap call.
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultbox);
    // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

        //SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.response();


        if (result != null) {

            XStream xstreams = new XStream(new DomDriver());
            String text = result.getProperty(0).toString();
            Testobjekt tob = (Testobjekt) xstreams.fromXML(text);
            t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultbox);        
            t.setText(tob.getName());
        }

*/
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        t.setText("FEHLER");

    }


  }


}
```

On Debugging I get an error on this line

```
     SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn; 
     SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.response();
```

Comment: what is the error? post the logcat

Comment: I dont get an error in logcat but i get the exception java.lang.classcastexception:org.ksopa2.soapFault

Comment: With this line SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse(); i get an other error.. i

Comment: With this line SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse(); i get an other error.. i get SoapFault - faultCode:'axis2ns25_Client'faultstring: 'The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) http://ip/WS/services"Service' faltactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@44c1d208

Comment: Try this: private static String URL = `"http://ip/WS/services/Service";`